# Does "==" only apply to certain data types?

Tags: java

In this program below:

```
public class medianTemp {
public static void main(String[] args){
    int length = args.length;
    int[] n = new int[length];
    n[0] = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);


    System.out.print(n[0] + " ");

    for (int i = 1; i < length; i++ ){
        String c = args[i];
        if (c.equals(".")){
            n[i] = n[i-1] + 0;
            System.out.print(n[i] + " ");
            }
        if (c.equals("+")){
            n[i] = n[i-1] + 1;
            System.out.print(n[i] + " ");
            }
        if (c.equals("-")){
            n[i] = n[i-1] - 1;
            System.out.print(n[i] + " ");
            }
```

Inside the `for` loop and inside the `if` statements. If I use for example `args[i] == "."` (instead of converting `args[i]` to `string`), the code above doesn't work and only the initial integer is displayed. Can someone please tell me why this happens?

Comment: `==` is for raw data types (`int`, `float`, `double`, ...). `equals()` is for objects (`String`, ...). Using `==` on objects compares referencing address.

Answer (score 4):

`==` compares objects based on their memory location when they are not primitives. Strings are **not** primitives, so while the content of 2 String objects may be equal the address of each one in memory is different and `==` returns false.

Answer (score 0):

In java, String objects (and nearly all objects) need to be compared with `equals()`. Two String objects may have the same value but be different objects (i.e. duplicates in memory *a la* `new String()`). The `==` comparison compares references.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use equals for string comparison.

Example from this website : http://blog.enrii.com/2006/03/15/java-string-equality-common-mistake/

```
String a = new String ("a");
String b = new String ("a");
System.out.println (a == b);
```

It returns false, while the following code returns true.

```
String a = new String ("a");
String b = new String ("a");
System.out.println (a.equals(b));
```

Answer (score -2):

`==` is a relational operator, referring to the relationships that values can have with one another.

Also, the `==` operator obviously means "Equal To" and only works for `raw` data types.

These types include double, int, and float. However, the `==` operator will not work in a boolean expression (only true/false works).

So in sum, it's really how you put your program together to get this operator to work. I recommend reading JAVA programming books such as the "JAVA 2" Series. Hope this helped!

Comment: What do you mean by `However, the == operator will not work in a boolean expression`?

Comment: == works for objects too. It just means something different to what you think it means. It means honestly and faithfully the same object, not "looks the same" which is what `equals()` typically means